# view XML as link in HTML

Tags: html, xml

I don't know how to explain this but here it goes.
I have below data. (from sql column via select query)

### `< error>< exitcode>1< /exitcode>< details>Details< /details>< /error>`

I want something in html where if you click Errors link. It will open a browser and produce below output.

```
'< error>< exitcode>1< /exitcode>< details>Details< /details>< /error>'
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I got you right, but if you want to convert your XML to HTML you can look up XSTL. Hope I am pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: I believe what your looking for is parseXML(). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513953/adding-xml-dom-elements-with-jquery-is-it-possible) and [this tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery) for more details.

Comment: I am sending an html email and that "ErrorLink" will open in another browser showing the error details in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

You can just output the `XML` data inside of the `<xmp>` tag in your html page:

```
<xmp>  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="unicode"?>  
 <error>
 <exitcode>1</exitcode>
 <details>Details</details>
</error>  
</xmp>
```

and the display in browser is :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Chen.. I like the output - that is what I am looking for but can we do something like this. There is an HTML page where there is an [ErrorLink] and if you click that link, that "output" will show in another browser.

Comment: Assume that the `errorlink` is : <a href="errorPage.html">ErrorLink</a>. You just put the `XML` data inside the `<xmp>` tag in the `errorPage.html`.

Comment: Nice! It worked Chen, I created two html files (errorPage.html and Main.html). Will this also work if they are in the same html file?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can have an anchor with a data uri with the error message in it

```html
<a href="data:text/plain,< error>< exitcode>1< /exitcode>< details>Details< /details>< /error>">&lt; error>&lt; exitcode>1&lt; /exitcode>&lt; details>Details&lt; /details>&lt; /error></a>
```